# how to change center location for Mapbox?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

i'm trying to add markers value(lat,lng) to database ( PHP / Wampserver).
using Mapbox api and i'd like for the map to open on the location that i'm currently working on but it won't change.
or if i can make it zoom on the latest marker add  that would work too

my code :

```php
    <script>

        var saved_markers = <?= get_saved_locations() ?>;
        var user_location = [36.168438,9.889008];
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZmFraHJhd3kiLCJhIjoiY2pscWs4OTNrMmd5ZTNra21iZmRvdTFkOCJ9.15TZ2NtGk_AtUvLd27-8xA';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9',
            center: user_location,
            zoom: 10,


        });
        //  geocoder here
        var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
            accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
            // limit results to Australia
            //country: 'IN',
        });

        var marker ;

        // After the map style has loaded on the page, add a source layer and default
        // styling for a single point.
        map.on('load', function() {
            addMarker(user_location,'load');
            add_markers(saved_markers);

            // Listen for the `result` event from the MapboxGeocoder that is triggered when a user
            // makes a selection and add a symbol that matches the result.
            geocoder.on('result', function(ev) {
                alert("aaaaa");
                console.log(ev.result.center);

            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

With the code you posted here, the map should be centered on [36.168438,9.889008].

If you want to change the center of the map after loading your markers, you can just call `map.setCenter()`, passing in the new coordinates as an array ([lng, lat]).

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#setcenter

Comment: I already changed it, [36.168438,9.889008] is the coordinates that i want but it didn't change, Its fixed someplace else which i couldn't find any trace of in the code !